# Configurable / dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, parameters, workflow

I want to build something like a pipeline, where I can put commands (converters, readers, writers...) together, like a linear workflow
and connect them by the given parameters of the commands. Everything should be serializable and a clean xml is mandatory, 
because graphical editor is not planned in the first step, so xml is edited (with a generated schema and intellisense support in VS this is no pain).

**Sample:**

```
<DataCommand name="AboFileReader"> 
<connection>
  <parameter name="filename"  direction="in"  type="string">
  <parameter name="tabledata" direction="out" type="DataTable">
</connection>       
</DataCommand>
<DataCommand name="TrimConverter"> 
<connection>
  <param name="tabledata" direction="in"  type="DataTable" >
  <param name="tabledata" direction="out" type="DataTable" >
</connection> 
</DataCommand>     
<DataCommand name="AboDataConverter"> 
<connection>
  <param name="tabledata" direction="in"  type="DataTable"  >
  <param name="tabledata" direction="out"  type="DataTable" >
</connection> 
</DataCommand> 
<DataCommand name="AboSqlWriter"> 
<connection>
  <param name="tabledata"  direction="in"  type="DataTable" >
</connection> 
</DataCommand>
```

Three different ways I can do it come to my mind and all of them have pros and cons and i don´t know which to choose.

First I thought 1. is the way to go, but then I came up with solution 3. because it gives a clean xml and is native serializable. 
For the next step (a editor) binding to GUI should be easy and a propertygrid doing reflection is not my first choice (reflection is always ugly), having a collection of parameters can easily be bound to the GUI.

Perhaps a combination of 1 and 3 is the way to go, to collect all parameters in a collection on startup?

**1. Data-Annotations**

```
[Parameter(Direction = "In", Description="...")]
public string FileName {get; set;}

[Parameter(Direction = "Out", Description="...")]
public DataTable Table {get; set;}
```

Pros:
+ native parameters are exposed
+ intellisense when coding

Cons:
- native serializing?
- ugly xml?

**2. Windows Workflow Foundation Style**

```
public InParameter<string> FileName {get; set;}

public OutParameter<DataTable> Table {get; set;}
```

Pros:
+ intellisense when coding
+ parameters are exposed
+ serializing works

Cons:
- ugly xml?

**3. Collection filled in constructor**

```
ObservableCollection<Parameter> Parameters {get; set;}

public Init()
{
  Parameters.Add( new Parameter() { Name="FileName", Type = typeOf(string),    Direction="In",  Description="..." } );
  Parameters.Add( new Parameter() { Name="Table",    Type = typeOf(DataTable), Direction="Out", Description="..." } );
}
```

Pros:
+ serializing works
+ clean xml

Cons:
- parameters are not exposed in sourcecode
- no intellisense when coding

What is your experience and what is the way to go?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  It seems a bit broad as it currently asked and might be a better fit for a site like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would pick a less verbose XML representation, something like:

```
<ReadFile filename="..." />
<Trim />
<Convert />
<WriteSQL />
```

I assume that most operations have a specific input and output type, so unless that should be configurable, there's no need to spell it out. That eliminates a bunch of properties, but not all, so your question remains. Ideally, you'll want something that:

1. is visible in the code structure - this serves as documentation, and lets your IDE help you
2. is easy to serialize - no repetetive, error-prone code
3. is easy to read in its serialized form - so you'll want clean XML

You'll want to use properties because of number 1. Because of number 2, you'll want to automatically determine which properties need to be serialized - that's where reflection comes in. Because of number 3, you'll want to serialize only those fields that are configurable - so you need something to differentiate those properties.

Using attributes to indicate which properties to expose is a good idea, as it clearly communicates their intention. It also allows you to ignore other properties, which keeps the serialization format clean. You can also choose to serialize only public properties, but attributes give you more flexibility. At worst they clutter up the code some more.

Here's how I would set up the basics:

```
public interface IOperation
{
    Type InputType { get; }
    Type OutputType { get; }

    object GetOutput(object input);
}
```

Each operation provides its own implementation of the `IOperation` interface:

```
public class ReadFileOperation : IOperation
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public Type InputType { get { return null; } } // No input
    public Type OutputType { get { return typeof(DataTable); } }

    public object GetOutput(object input)
    {
        // TODO: Read file into DataTable here!
    }
}
```

If you do have operations that can be configured to work with different input or output types, then giving `InputType` or `OutputType` a setter and a `[Parameter]` attribute should work just fine.

You can write a single function that looks for all types that implement IOperation, and store a list of properties for each type. Then, when parsing or writing, you look up the current type and use its list of properties. This function only needs to be called once, and if performance is really a problem, you could use its output to generate parsing/writing code when your application starts up, but that's not something I would do unless I really had to.

```
public Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> DetectParameterProperties()
{
    Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> lookup = new Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>>();

    IEnumerable<Type> operations = Assembly
        .GetAssembly(typeof(IOperation))
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IOperation).IsAssignableFrom(t));

    foreach (Type operation in operations)
    {
        lookup[operation] = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> parameters = operation.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(ParameterAttribute)));
        foreach (PropertyInfo parameter in parameters)
            lookup[operation].Add(parameter);
    }

    return lookup;
}
```

Note that as you provide more configuration options, error handling becomes more important. A simple type-check to ensure that all input and output types match is good, but some operations may need their own checks to ensure they aren't misconfigured in some other way.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestion, as I understand you right, you build a mix of 1. and 2.? The Xml should not be verbose (but I mean the types and different namespaces should not appear) but yours seem a little to spare for me. I have to say, that multiple input/output parameters should be possible (sorry, in my sample I did not use them). I want return List<OutParameters>, e.g. when my data gets validated an split up, I propabaly get two datatables (e.g. "ValidAbos" and "InvalidAbos").

Comment: No, it's pretty much your approach 1, not 2. Different outputs does change the situation somewhat... do you pick one of the outputs and ignore the other(s), or do you want to process all outputs (in that case, it's no longer really a linear process, but a branching one)?

Comment: Branching isn´t needed I think and would make the whole thing complex and a complete workflow. The e.g. invalid abos can be written to a file in the validator itself and don´t needed to processed futhermore, but only having on parameter seems a little restricted. when having multipe paramters, then I have to name them. I have a question regarding your solution, why did you mark the filename  as [Parameter], but doesn´t return string as InputType? What is the advantage, of your solution? As I understand compared to 1 serializing would work and compared to 2, the in/out types are  visible?

Comment: I don't have a specific reason to make filename a parameter - whether it's better to pass it as input, or to make it a property, or perhaps allow both, depends on the situation. I think you're better suited to make those decisions because you know how it will be used. :)

Comment: As for multiple outputs, is that generally 'normal' and 'erroneous' output (or an equivalent: matching/non-matching, etc.)? Or do you have operations in mind that can produce a much wider range of output?